# Custom JS for RadioSelect inlines in Django admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Here is working example on adding custom JS code (any HTML indeed) to each one of inlines:
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1261/

But I cannot reproduce it for `RadioSelect` type fields in admin.

Model `model.py`:

```
class Work(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)

    IMAGE = 'IM'
    VIDEO = 'VI'
    CONTENT_TYPE = (
        (IMAGE, 'Image'),
        (VIDEO, 'Video'),
    )

    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                    choices=CONTENT_TYPE,
                                    default=IMAGE)
```

And `admin.py`:

```
class WorkInline(admin.TabularInline):
    fields = ('content_type',)
    radio_fields = {"content_type": admin.VERTICAL}
    model = Work
```

I can't figure out how to override `render()` for `radio_fields` (like it's done for `TextInput` in example above) to inject my code into them. Or may be there is some easier way?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can I somehow inherit `radio_fields` widget?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should be call the file since the forms.py, you should a create a class like this:

   ```
   class WorkForm(forms.ModelForm):

       class Meta:
            model = Work

       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(WorkForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['content_type'].widget = ColorPickerWidget()
   ```
2. Don't forget import the widget

Comment: Just read Django docs, and it says "`formfield_overrides` won’t let you change the widget on relation fields that have `raw_id_fields` or `radio_fields` set. That’s because `raw_id_fields` and `radio_fields` imply custom widgets of their own." So I'm afraid it couldn't be done through widget mechanism.